# Using mapbox js, how do I change the style of a map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have included my `js` and `css` for `mapbox` in the `header`:

```
<script src='//api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='//api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Added the map html:

```
<div id='map'></div>
<style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { width:100%; height:471px; }
</style>
```

And then in `js` made a map:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic21pY2tpZSIsImEiOiJjaWtiM2JkdW0wMDJudnRseTY0NWdrbjFnIn0.WxGYL18BJjWUiNIu-r3MSA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([40, -74.50], 3);
```

I don't know how to change the style of it to one I have in `mapbox` studio.

I have two style urls in mapbox studio:

```
mapbox://styles/smickie/cikb3fhvi0063cekqns0pk1f1

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/smickie/cikb3fhvi0063cekqns0pk1f1.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic21pY2tpZSIsImEiOiJjaWtiM2JkdW0wMDJudnRseTY0NWdrbjFnIn0.WxGYL18BJjWUiNIu-r3MSA#1.4858291953347187/42.16057367191365/1.6334765316350683/0
```

How do I apply these styles to the map in my page?

This is the api but I can't find how to change styles anywhere: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.4/

Comment: Mapbox just released v2.3.0 of Mapbox.js API, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Updated this answer because of the introduction of v2.3.0 of the Mapbox.js API. It add a `L.mapbox.styleLayer` which can handle styles created using Mapbox studio:

```
L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/emerald-v8').addTo(map);
```

Example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/stylelayer/

Answer before Mapbox 2.3.0:

You're using the wrong API, those styles are for use with the Mapbox-GL api:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/

If you want to use classic Mapbox API like you're doing now you need to use Mapbox Studio Classic to create your own styled tileset:

https://www.mapbox.com/studio/classic/